# Exception thrown when building Microsoft.Dnx.Host with Sake and KoreBuild

Tags: c#, linux, build, mono, asp.net-core

I cloned the the asp.net beta8 repository today and when I went to build it I ran into an error.

```
Building Microsoft.Dnx.Host for DNX,Version=v4.5.1
Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
fail: Exit code 1 from dnu
fail: Stack trace: 
...
```

The full stack trace can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/E6XaaFKV). I went through and found where build.sh was causing this error and I found that it was caused by the following command.

```
mono packages/Sake/tools/Sake.exe -I packages/KoreBuild/build -f makefile.shade "$@"
```

I am running

```
`Mono JIT compiler version 4.0.4 (Stable 4.0.4.1/5ab4c0d Tue Aug 25 23:11:51 UTC 2015)`
`DNU Version:      1.0.0-rc1-15890`
`DNX Version:      1.0.0-rc1-15890`
```

Any ideas as to why?